# How to fix ParameterCircularReferenceException?

Tags: php, symfony, environment-variables, docker-compose

I have a symfony2 appliciation. We have previously set up a docker-compose stack for development, and this is why we want all its configuration to bet set via environment variables instead of the parameters.yml.

Hence I replaced the content of my parameters.yml from:

```
parameters:
    locale: 'en'
    secret: 'SOME_SECURITY_TOKEN'
    ...
```

to:

```
parameters:
    locale: '%locale%'
    secret: '%secret%'
    ...
```

My `docker-compose.yml` file contains:

```
my_app:
    hostname: my-app
    build: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
        - "9080:80"
        - "9043:433"
    environment:
        LOCALE: en
        SECRET: SOME_SECURITY_TOKEN
        ...
```

Yet after rebuilding my container I get the exception:

```
ParameterCircularReferenceException in ParameterBag.php line 209: Circular reference detected for parameter "secret" ("secret" > "secret").
    1. in ParameterBag.php line 209
    2. at ParameterBag->resolveString('%secret%', array('secret' => true)) in ParameterBag.php line 185
    3. at ParameterBag->resolveValue('%secret%', array('secret' => true)) in ParameterBag.php line 214
    4. at ParameterBag->resolveString('%secret%', array('secret' => true)) in ParameterBag.php line 185
    5. at ParameterBag->resolveValue('%secret%', array()) in ParameterBag.php line 175
    6. at ParameterBag->resolveValue(array('secret' => '%secret%', 'router' => array('resource' => '%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml', 'strict_requirements' => null), 'form' => null, 'csrf_protection' =>
       null, 'validation' => array('enable_annotations' => true), 'templating' => array('engines' => array('twig')), 'default_locale' => '%locale%', 'trusted_hosts' => null, 'trusted_proxies' => null,
       'session' => array('handler_id' => 'api.session.handler.memcached'), 'fragments' => null, 'http_method_override' => true), array()) in ParameterBag.php line 175
    7. at ParameterBag->resolveValue(array(array('secret' => '%secret%', 'router' => array('resource' => '%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml', 'strict_requirements' => null), 'form' => null,
       'csrf_protection' => null, 'validation' => array('enable_annotations' => true), 'templating' => array('engines' => array('twig')), 'default_locale' => '%locale%', 'trusted_hosts' => null,
       'trusted_proxies' => null, 'session' => array('handler_id' => 'api.session.handler.memcached'), 'fragments' => null, 'http_method_override' => true), array('router' =>
       array('resource' => '%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml', 'strict_requirements' => true), 'profiler' => array('only_exceptions' => false)))) in MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 45
    8. at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php line 39
    9. at MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in Compiler.php line 107
   10. at Compiler->compile(object(ContainerBuilder)) in ContainerBuilder.php line 589
   11. at ContainerBuilder->compile() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2687
   12. at Kernel->initializeContainer() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2465
   13. at Kernel->boot() in bootstrap.php.cache line 2496
   14. at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in app_dev.php line 30
```

Yet in my container I do see the env variables:

```
le-container:/var/www/my-app# env
SECRET=SOME_SECURITY_TOKEN
LOCALE=en
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, adding a prefix to my environment variable fixed the issue:

```
parameters:
    locale: '%foo_locale%'
    secret: '%foo_secret%'
```

and of course whenever the variable is set as well. My current working theory is that symfony doesn't like having the same parameter name and env variable, yet I am not sure.

Comment: what you describe is it ;-) the parameterbag-class parses the "parameter notated values" and looks in parameters.yml for them so this is endless

Comment: @johnSmith It seems you have located the responsible part in the symfony2 sources. Could you please add a link to the relevant part? I think I am going to open an issue about it on their github.

Comment: i think you misunderstood, your actual problem was that the parameter-names were equal, so the class parses the reference and finds it first again in parameters.yml where it finds the reference again and so on, but it is an inbuilt feature to use external parameters ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
parameters:
    locale: '%locale%'
    secret: '%secret%'
```

Is useless construction, locale and secret already is parameters. Just remove this block.

Comment: I am injecting the values via environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to use [external parameters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html). Prefix your variables with "SYMFONY__". In your case it would be:

```
my_app:
    ...
    environment:
         SYMFONY__APP__LOCALE: en
         SYMFONY__APP__SECRET: SOME_SECURITY_TOKEN
    ...
```

And in your parameters you can call it as followed:

```
parameters:
    locale: %app.locale%
    secret: %app.secret%
```